# StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RegistrationComponent -> ToastrManager]

Tags: unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine, toastr

[Error while testing a component due to toastr manager][1]

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjhd9.png">
```

I am not using toastr manager in this component and still it is showing error.

```
"Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[RegistrationComponent -> ToastrManager]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[RegistrationComponent -> ToastrManager]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ToastrManager!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because some of the child components that are present inside `RegistrationComponent` are using it.

So, when you are creating `RegistrationComponent` , the child component UI is also rendered in testing browser and it is failing.